# Inserting Encrypted data in postgres

Tags: hibernate, postgresql

In our database, credit card number is encrypted, to store encrypted data in postgresql database we are doing following way.

```
\set pubkey '''' `sed -e "s/'/''/g"  -e 's/\\n/\\r\\n/g'  -e  's/\\/\\\\/g' < /home/vinit/fnpub.key` '''' 

 \set pvtkey '''' `sed -e "s/'/''/g"  -e 's/\\n/\\r\\n/g'  -e  's/\\/\\\\/g' < /home/vinit/fnpvt.key` '''' 

select pgp_pub_decrypt(number, dearmor(:pvtkey),'testypassword' ) from payment_detail limit 2;
```

Application is using hibernate, how to insert data with encryption and read decrypted data using hibernate?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

First, I think your key management leaves a lot to be desired.  You are going to have lots of problems with key management.  Please start by reading Craig's excellent reply to me on this question: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/35296/database-encryption-and-key-management-with-pg-crypto

In this case you probably should have user keys stored somewhere in the db, protected by a pass phrase, and then use those to encrypt symmetric keys for the credit card numbers.  You can then encrypt those keys with public keys to ensure that only authorized users can access them.  The fact is you are going to have to store the keys somewhere.

Now in my application we expect only two or three people to have access and everyone will have access to all passwords.  So a query for encrypting a password looks like:

```
SELECT pgp_sym_encrypt($1, -- new password
                  pgp_pub_decrypt(last_resort_key,
                                  pgp_sym_decrypt_bytea(priv_key, $2) -- current passphrase
                  ))
  FROM user_key
 WHERE login = session_user;
```

(using libpq formats here).  Note that we use pg users as app users.

Once you have the relevant data in the database, your sql queries can be relatively straight-forward to write.

One note, it is possible that error logs could reveal keys or worse.  You probably want to retain as few logs as possible and keep them for as little time as possible